# Pass exclusive selection to ASP.NET form

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm making an application in ASP.NET MVC that allows you to post a form with two text fields and a string set from an exclusive selection. This means a list of strings shown to the user that when selected (only one can be selected at a time) and submitted (this field is required), the text from the selection will be passed to the controller. I've tried using list groups in bootstrap, then adding a JQuery event for onclick, and setting the value of a hidden form field. the click handler works fine but the value setting is having an issue. Here's my code:

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="list-group" style="overflow-y: auto; height: 300px; width: 100%;">
                @Html.ActionLink("Create new occupation", "createOccupation", "Occupation", null, new { @class = "list-group-item" })
                @foreach (var occ in Get.AllOccupations().ToList())
                {
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">@occ.Title</a>
                }

            </div>
        </div>

<script>
    $('.list-group-item').on('click', function () {
        $('.list-group a.active').removeClass('active');
        $('#OccupancySelectBox').val($(this).find("a").first().text());
        $(this).addClass('active');
    })
</script>
```

Comment: what about a simple dropdown list?

Comment: Or a radio button group?

Comment: What I was trying to ask is, how do I pass those values to the controller without this JQuery rubbish?

Comment: well I would use a standard dropdownlist (`<select>`) control. Then when you post back your form, the value of the selected item will be automatically included in the model that's posted.

Comment: the reason you need jQuery right now is you're using hyperlinks to draw your UI, instead of standard form elements, such as `<input>` or `<select>`. A radio button group as suggested by Stephen above is also a valid solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I was trying to ask is, how do I pass those values to the
>   controller without this JQuery rubbish?

Sure. You can use the normal form posting without jQuery/ajax if you prefer that way.

Assuming you have a view model like this

```
public class JobSelectionVm
{
  public string FirstName {set;get;}
  public string LastName { set;get;}
  public int SelectedJobId {set;get;
}
```

Now your view will be strongly typed to this view model

```
@model JobSelectionVm
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
   <label>First Name</label>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.FirstName)

   <label>Last Name</label>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.LastName)

   <label>Select an Occupation</label>
   var jobList =  Get.AllOccupations().ToList(); 
   foreach (var occ in jobList)
   {
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(f => Model.SelectedJobId, ev.JobId)
      <div>@ev.Title</div>
   }
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

This will generate radion buttons for items in the jobList collection. When you submit the form, the selected job's id will be available in the `SelectedJobId` property value.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(JobSelectionVm model)
{
   // check model.FirstName,model.LastName, model.SelectedJobId
  // to do : return something
}
```

Also, you can update the view model to have a property which carries data for the radio buttons( Get.AllOccupations()) so that you can avoid calling `Get.AllOccupations()` in the razor view.